# Parsing large HTML files with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to parse http://www.pro-medic.ru/index.php?ht=246&perpage=all with Nokogiri, but unfortunately I can't get all items from the page.

My simple test code is:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

html = Nokogiri::HTML open('http://www.pro-medic.ru/index.php?ht=246&perpage=all')
p html.css('ul.products-grid-compact li .goods_container').count
```

It returns only 83 items but the real count is about 186.

I thought that the problem could be in `open`, but it seems that function reads the HTML page correctly.

Has anybody faced the same problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file seems to exceed Nokogiri's parser limits. You can relax the limits by adding the [`HUGE`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/ParseOptions#HUGE-constant) flag:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

url = 'http://www.pro-medic.ru/index.php?ht=246&perpage=all'
html = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)) do |config|
  config.options |= Nokogiri::XML::ParseOptions::HUGE
end
html.css('ul.products-grid-compact li .goods_container').count
#=> 186
```

Note that `|=` is a bitwise OR assignment operator, don't confuse it with the logical operator `||=`

According to [Parse Options](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html#parse_options), you can also set this flag via `config.huge`

Comment: Thank you so much Stefan! I supposed there must be some restriction about page size. But `html.css('ul.products-grid-compact li .goods_container').count` now takes too much time to compute. Is there some way to speed it up? Or it is just because of large page size and there is nothing to do with it?

Comment: A quick check reveals that the markup is broken. It results in a node tree with a depth of 571 and such a tree takes very long to traverse. You have to sanitize the page before feeding it into Nokogiri. I have used Safari to save a fixed version of the page and it took merely half a second to count the elements (without any config changes).

Comment: Stefan can you tell me how do you check markup? Is there any way to do it from code automatically?

Comment: I mean not to check from code but to sanitize.
Something like `source = open(url).sanitize`

Comment: Sorry, no. Maybe the folks at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com can recommend a library.

Comment: Note that for a single config option you can apply it far more simply by using the config method: `html = Nokogiri.HTML( open(url), &:huge )`

Comment: @Phrogz nice catch, didn't think of that!