# Nokogiri not parsing exported bookmark html from Delicious correctly

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I cannot seem to figure why Nokogori is not parsing this html file correctly. This html file is a bookmark export from Delicious. It has 400 links in it but always only parses out 254 links. I have other Delicious html export files that also only find 254 links (that have differing link amounts) and one that parses the links correctly (over 2000 links), so it seems as though there may be specific links that are causing the issue, but I'm really not sure. I'm linking to the html here, since the html puts the body of this post over the character limit. This is an example of the html (the actual html has over 400  tags):

```
<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<!-- This is an automatically generated file.
It will be read and overwritten.
Do Not Edit! -->
<TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE>
<H1>Bookmarks</H1>
<DL><p>
<DT><A HREF="http://www.lecartelclothing.com/" ADD_DATE="1459226337" PRIVATE="1" TAGS="montreal,art,design">Le Cartel | Le Cartel Clothing Inc.</A>
<DT><A HREF="http://parkdaleprojectread.org/" ADD_DATE="1459226204" PRIVATE="1" TAGS="ngo">Parkdale Project Read</A>
<DT><A HREF="http://darkmp3.ru/" ADD_DATE="1458608207" PRIVATE="1" TAGS="music,blogs,music_blog,download">Dark mp3</A>
<DT><A HREF="http://www.sbs.com.au/programs/the-family-law/article/family-law-episode-guide" ADD_DATE="1458603937" PRIVATE="1" TAGS="asian,china,cinema">The Family Law: Watch the series | Programs</A>
<DT><A HREF="http://asiansdoingeverything.tumblr.com/" ADD_DATE="1458602744" PRIVATE="1" TAGS="asian,blogs,china">Asians Doing Everything</A>
</DL></p>
```

I'm uploading the html file with the Carrierwave gem and parsing it. This code I've been using is (where html_upload is a model instance using Carrierwave):

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse html_upload.file.read
puts doc.css('a').count
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]". You need the minimal input (HTML) _in the question itself_, along with the expected output. Don't expect us to go off-site to track that information down or to reduce it for you; Help us help you instead. Links rot then break, and when they do your question will not make any sense to us or anyone else looking for a similar solution.

Comment: I tried but was hitting the character limit and at the time I thought that the length of the html was relevant to the answer.

Comment: Since you know that's not true it'd be good to fix the question so it meets the guidelines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Nokogiri does not parse a document as you'd expect, always check `doc.errors`.

Here's what I get when I try to parse the raw content from your gist:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri.HTML(DATA.read)
puts doc.errors.last
#=> Excessive depth in document: 256 use XML_PARSE_HUGE option
```

The problem here is that the HTML file has tons of unclosed tags (mostly `<DT>`, which Nokogiri (or rather, libxml2) is trying to nest within one another. Illustrated:

```
doc = Nokogiri.XML(html,&:noblanks)
puts doc.to_xhtml(indent:2)
#=> <TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE>
#=> <H1>Bookmarks</H1>
#=> <DL>
#=>   <p>
#=>     <DT>
#=>       <A HREF="http://boomjacak.com/" ...>BOOM JACAK</A>
#=>       <DT>
#=>         <A HREF="http://tropicaliainfursnyc.com/" ...>Tropicalia in Furs Baby!</A>
#=>         <DT>
#=>           <A HREF="https://uptimerobot.com/" ...>Uptime Robot</A>
#=>           <DT>
#=>             <A HREF="http://yagphotovoice.tumblr.com/" ...>EYE SPY</A>
#=>             <DT>
#=>               <A HREF="http://glitterbeat.com/" ...>Glitterbeat &#x2013; Vibrant Global Sounds</A>
#=>               <DT>
#=>                 <A HREF="http://www.puzz.com/stickelsframegames.html" ...>Stickels Frame Games</A>
#=>                 <DT>
#=>                   <A HREF="http://silentdiscosquad.com/" ...>Silent Disco Squad</A>
#=>                   <DT>
#=>                     <A HREF="http://innerfire.ca/" ...>None</A>
#=>                     <DT>
#=>                       <A HREF="http://lidopepper.tumblr.com/" ...>Lido Pimienta - La Papessa</A>
#=>                       <DT>
#=>                         <A HREF="http://cabaretdiaspora.wordpress.com/" ...>Radio Cabaret Diaspora | Musiques urbaines</A>
#=>                         <DT>
```

You can tell Nokogiri to forge on using the ['huge' config option](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/ParseOptions):

```
doc = Nokogiri.HTML( myhtml, &:huge )
```

I'd personally just lightly fix up the HTML in question using `gsub`:

```
html = DATA.read
html.gsub! /<DT>.+?<\/A>$/, '\\0</DT>'
doc = Nokogiri.HTML(html)
p doc.css('a').length
#=> 399
```

*(I checked: there are only 399 links in the file, not 400.)*

Comment: Thank you! This is a great lead. I ended up using the 'huge' parse option:       doc = Nokogiri::HTML(data) do |config|
        config.huge
      end This answer was also helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37542491/parsing-large-html-files-with-nokogiri/37542948

Comment: Glad you found an answer. I'll put that in here to make it easier for others to find. Note that you can do that with less typing: `doc = Nokogiri.HTML( myhtml, &:huge )`

Comment: Yep, planning on selecting is as the answer and upvoting. One last comment is that the problem actually is not that there are too many unclosed tags (every bookmark export uses unclosed <DT> tags for some reason), it's that it looks it has too many nested tags within one tag (the limit seems to be 256).

Comment: @TenJack Right, but those are the same thing. With the code `<DT>...<DT>...<DT>...<DT>...` the interpretation of those by an XML parser is that the second DT is a child of the first, the third is a child of the second, and so on. After 256 levels of just adding children, by default libxml2 bails out because it assumes there's something wrong. By leaving the tags unclosed, they are nested (from an XML standpoint).

Comment: See my edit that includes a pretty-printed version of how libxml2 is misunderstanding the HTML. It shows the nesting that results from the unclosed `</DT>` tags.

Comment: Not fixing the HTML and expecting a parser to interpret the markup, is asking for problems even if it can load the file. The parser will try to add closing tags but usually won't do it correctly, resulting in a mangled DOM which is very difficult to navigate because it won't match your selectors based on your idea of where tags should be. Relying on `huge` will back you into the corner, whereas fixing the markup will put things right. As @Phrogz said, use `gsub!` to fix the problem.